# Htaccess RewriteCond taking me to 404 - folder exists

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have two htaccess rewrite conditions:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?gotham.rentals$
RewriteRule !^gothamrentals/ /gothamrentals%{REQUEST_URI}  [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?sofla.biz$
RewriteRule !^southflorida/ /southflorida%{REQUEST_URI}  [L]
```

The first one works, the second one does not (404 from the server). What gives? The folder southflorida exists and has the same permissions as the folder gothamrentals.

Comment: If you can provide more relevant info from the error log. Apache HTTPD does not give arbitrary 404 errors. You can also temporarily switch to include R flag for external redirection and see with your own eyes where the request is ending, and which element is not really present where you are landing.

Answer (score 1):

The answer I used was adding:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

To the southflorida directory. I suspect, maybe "/" was getting added to the url and the child htaccess was taking care of gothamrentals.